# ReactJS: Create a select after a find from another list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would to create two select in which the value ,choosen from select1, is used to make a find and show another list in select2.

```
const [application, setApplication] = useState('');
const applicationChoosen = () => {
    const operators = application
      ? operatorsList.find(it => {
          it.app.appCod.appCod.toString() === application.toString();
        })
      : null;
    return (
      <AvInput id="operators" data-cy="operators" type="select" name="operators" className="form-control">
        {operators
          ? operators.map(otherEntity => {
              <option value={otherEntity.app.appCod.appCod} key={otherEntity.app.appCod.appCod}>
                {otherEntity.operatorsName}
              </option>;
            })
          : null}
      </AvInput>
    );
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name && value) {
      setApplication(value);
    }
  };


    return(
    <AvGroup>
                    <Label id="applicationLabel" for="application">
                      Applicazione
                    </Label>
                    <AvInput
                      id="application"
                      data-cy="application"
                      type="select"
                      name="application"
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                      <option value="" key="0" />
                      {Applicaziones
                        ? Applicaziones.map(otherEntity => {
                            return (
                              <option value={otherEntity.appCod} key={otherEntity.appCod}>
                                {otherEntity.appDescription}
                              </option>
                            );
                          })
                        : null}
                    </AvInput>
                  </AvGroup>
                  <AvGroup>{applicationChoosen}</AvGroup>
    )
```

So in the first select (Applicaziones) I choose the first value (otherEntity.appCod) and I save this value in the state, using handleChange, and the using this value for the second select (applicationChoosen).

In applicationChoosen I have a problem:

1. const operators results undefined (but It should shows the operatorsName)

How can I do to show the in the second list (in the second select ) the values filtered between `it.app.appCod.appCod.toString() === application.toString()`

Comment: You should always return a single component, so either wrap the whole thing into a `<div>` or `<React.Fragment>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was full of react errors, I hope this gives you enough guidance to fix your issues:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const operatorsList = [{ app: { appCod: { appCod: '' } } }];

const ApplicationChoosen = ({ firstApplication }) => {
  if (!firstApplication) {
    return <div />;
  }

  const operators = operatorsList.find(
    it => it.app.appCod.appCod.toString() === firstApplication.toString(),
  );

  return (
    <AvInput
      id="operators"
      data-cy="operators"
      type="select"
      name="operators"
      className="form-control"
    >
      {operators &&
        operators.map(otherEntity => (
          <option
            value={otherEntity.app.appCod.appCod}
            key={otherEntity.app.appCod.appCod}
          >
            {otherEntity.operatorsName}
          </option>
        ))}
    </AvInput>
  );
};

export default function({ Applicaziones }) {
  const [application, setApplication] = useState('');

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name && value) {
      setApplication(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AvGroup>
        <Label id="applicationLabel" for="application">
          Applicazione
        </Label>
        <AvInput
          id="application"
          data-cy="application"
          type="select"
          name="application"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <option value="" key="0" />
          {Applicaziones
            ? Applicaziones.map(otherEntity => {
                return (
                  <option value={otherEntity.appCod} key={otherEntity.appCod}>
                    {otherEntity.appDescription}
                  </option>
                );
              })
            : null}
        </AvInput>
      </AvGroup>
      <AvGroup>
        <ApplicationChoosen firstApplication={application} />
      </AvGroup>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I have only a question.. I'm in typescript and I have a problem with operators.map, because I receive the message that property map doesn't exist in the type "....". Should I define an interface for operators?

Comment: I don't know how your OperatorsList looks like, the value that is *found* in your Operators list should be an array, otherwise you will not be able to map through it.

Comment: I have defined  `type RoleOperator: any[] | any` 
and then   `const operators: RoleOperator = operatorsList.find(....)` 

In this way the map is not recognize as error, but the operators is undefined

Comment: You still have to find out what structure your operatorsList has and how you get the options from it. `console.log()` is your friend, use it frequently to find out exactly the variable values you are working with.